# FatalErrorException in HtmlServiceProvider.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'am new in Laravel 5 and I don't know how to solve this issue. This is my error when I try to put some opening a form using laravelCollective.

> FatalErrorException in HtmlServiceProvider.php line 52:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getToken()
>   1. in HtmlServiceProvider.php line 52

Can anyone who can help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like it is something wrong with configuration of laraelcollective

Comment: Have you configured sessions?

Comment: I configure composer.json file and I put this line on require:                                       `  "laravel/framework": "5.4",
     "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the newer version of the package and run composer update.

Change the package info in the composer.json file.

```
"laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

Update the package.

```
composer update
```